# Multiplication table with rows and columns

Tags: c, formatting, printf, multiplication

How can I make multiplication table to look like this: [http://i.imgur.com/rR6JSua.png](https://i.imgur.com/rR6JSua.png) ?

With my code it only has one column.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1;i <= 9;i++)
    {   
        for(j = 1;j <= 9;j++)
        {
            printf("%d * %d  = %d\n",i , j,i*j);
        }
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n",i , 10,i*10);
        printf("\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The image link is broken, please update with a new image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

for(i = 1;i <= 9;i+=3)
{

  for(j = 1;j <= 10;j++)
  {

       printf("%2d * %2d = %2d ",i , j,(i)*j);
       printf("%2d * %2d = %2d ",i+1 , j,(i+1)*j);
       printf("%2d * %2d = %d\n",i+2, j,(i+2)*j);
  }
  printf("\n");
} 
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @AndriusK I might be too picky, and maybe for you it is perfect, but your teacher might have different opinion. Look at alignment of columns. You were given that exercise for a reason. Match it to look **exactly** the same(every space, every character, then it will be perfect).

Answer (score 0):

You have to print your table line by line, not column by columne.

So you have to

```
printf("%d*%d=%d %d*%d=%d %d*%d=%d\n",...);
```

Rest figure out yourself, if you have problems, write and I'll help you further.

Comment: What's the point in giving him/her complete code to something that's definetely for educational purpose( homework, I mean).

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i, j=1;


while(j<=9){
      for(i=1;i<=9;i++){       
          printf("%d * %d = %3d    ",i , j,i*j);
      }
      printf("\n");
      j++;
}

return 0;
}
```