# how to make multiplication table with loop in C

Tags: c

```
int main(void){

    int number;

    while(1) {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("%d", number);

        if (number >= 1 && number <= 9) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                printf("%d X %d = %d \n", number, j, number*j);
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (number >= 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sorry.. my english is not very well :(

this is my multiplication table
if i input negative number. while > break
but this code input negative number > else....

how can i modify this code

i wanna your smart knowledge for me :)

---

use to Google Translation

Program termination when inputting number less than 0
Restart loop statement when entering characters

Comment: Your else if (number >= 0) needs to be else if (number < 0)

Comment: "*while > break but this code input negative number > else....*" Please excuse, but I just do not get what you want to express. Perhaps better use Gxxgle-Translate?

Comment: use to Google Translation

Program termination when inputting number less than 0 Restart loop statement when entering characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplication table with rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19223788/608639)

Answer (score 3):

You are not handling negative number at all.

The below `else if` block hits only if `number` is equal to `0` or greater than `9` since your first `if` handles number from `1` to `9`.

```
else if (number >= 0) {
                ^^-> greater than or equal to 0.
```

So change it to

```
else if (number <= 0) {
                ^^->less than or equal to 0.
```

---

> Restart loop statement when entering characters.

You can use return value from `scanf` to restart the loop upon entering `char`

```
while(1) {
        int ret = scanf("%d", &number);
        if (ret != 1)
        {
           printf("enter valid number\n");
           continue;
        }
        printf("number:%d", number);

        if (number >= 1 && number <= 9) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                printf("%d X %d = %d \n", number, j, number*j);
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (number <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks....and then if i input character, how can make to loop this code??

Comment: @SamsonSEO You can check the return value of `scanf`. It will return `0` if you enter `char`. otherwise `1` if you enter valid integer.

Comment: @SamsonSEO Check my updated answer.